# Meta-* / "insert-completions" Fails for Completions Defined via "complete -F ..."

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple completion function that is doing what I want with one exception. Its completions are not expanded when I type M-* ("insert-completions") the way file completions are.

Is this an inherent limitation or something I can enable?

I just tried this on a different computer (with a slightly different version of BASH) and it worked there.

- Works: 3.2.25(1)-release (Linux, CentOS 5.5)
- No-Go: 3.2.48(1)-release (MacOS X 10.6.7)

**Update**: I am looking for an hypothesis that might explain the discrepancy between these two systems.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following code [from this web page](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) to my `.bash_profile`:

```
_foo() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="--help --verbose --version"

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _foo foo
```

---

`foo --` gets expanded to `foo --help --verbose --version` when pressing `Meta-*` in Terminal.app.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

---

So: I cannot reproduce with the same version of `bash`on Mac OS X 10.6.7. Did you change your environment after installation, e.g. installing third party unix stuff via Macports/Fink/Homebrew? Try using a fresh Terminal configuration by creating a new user account.

Make sure you actually are pressing `Meta` -- it's configurable in Terminal. If you don't set this option, there's no `Meta`:

[image]

Do other `Meta` shortcuts from `readline` work?

---

If this doesn't work: Since 10.7.0 Lion is not yet commercially available I suggest you just expect pre-release software to have bugs and report them to the proper [site](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Yes, other Meta- work. This is Snow Leopard. That's just what "uname -a" produces.

Comment: @Randall In your question, you wrote you use 10.7.0, which is the unreleased "Lion" scheduled for later this year. What do you press when `Option` is not your `Meta` key? You need to use an `Esc` sequence, i.e. first press `Esc` (don't hold), then press `*` afterwards. Also works for me.

Comment: All I can tell you is that I'm running Snow Leopoard 10.6.7 and when I run "uname -a" it says the kernel is "Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0". It is by no means a pre-release system. And as I said, Using Option for Meta, as I've configured it, will trigger insert-completions for file system-based completion.

Comment: @Randall In that case, I suspect a problem with your completion function. I just put mine in `.bash_profile`. Try to do just that with the code I provided and see if it works then.

Comment: @Randall Darwin follows a different versioning scheme than Mac OS X. Whenever Mac OS X gains a minor version (10.5 -> 10.6), Darwin gains a major version (9.x -> 10.x). Please edit your post to mention the correct Mac OS X version.

Comment: @Daniel: In fact, I based my completion function on the very same Web page you did.

Comment: @Randall Yeah, but I edited a different file -- `.bash_profile`. Also, did you remember to open a new shell after editing these files? Did you try it with the exact original function, or only one *based* on that one?

Comment: It works for individual completions but not for the "insert all possible completions." *That* is the question. Why one and not the other while the insert-completions M-asterisk *does* work for filesystem completions?

Comment: @Randall You didn't even show us your code and don't do what I suggest, or at least don't report the results. It works on my machine, and I explained, in detail, what I did. If you do the ***exact same thing***, no *based on*, no *followed the same guide*, just do what I posted in the answer, does it work for you, yes or no?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: @randall does it work with another user Account?